# Can I pass more than 2 parameters or an array with onCommand event in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, events, parameters, event-handling

the question is above and it is short. I am trying to pass more parameters through a button in a repeater itemtemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would append the values to a string with a delimeter, like this:

```
CommandArgument='<%# String.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", Eval("Column1"), Eval("Column2"), Eval("Column3"))'%>
```

When you get into the event handler, just split the string at the delimeter, like this:

```
var columnList = e.CommandArgument.Split('|');
```

Answer (score 0):

The CommandArgument property takes a string. So you could put several values into that property in a comma separated format, e.g:

```
button.CommandArgument = "param1,param2,param3";
```

Then in the OnClick event handler, simply split the CommandArgument property:

```
var parameters = e.CommandArgument.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a dumb way to walk around this problem.

pass all the stuff into CommandArgument and use string.split to get the parameter array.

```
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PersonId") + ";" + Eval("PersonName") %>'

string[] paras = argu.Split(';');
```

Comment: You should use code blocks wherever your demonstrating code. It's much easier to read.